# Computed Property Not Recomputing

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, computed-properties

I have a form where a user selects 1 option from 3 different `<select>` tags. I want to store the selected options in an array. So, I thought this would be a good case to use computed properties. I tried setting up item0, item1, and item2 as computed properties which in turn set the corresponding index in an array to a value retrieved from the value passed from the setter:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#vue-app',
    data: {
        items: []
    },
    computed: {
        item0: {
            get: function () {
                return this.items[0].id;
            },
            set: function (itemId) {
                this.items[0] = this.getItem(newValue);
                //update other values
            }
        },
        item1: {
            get: function () {
                return this.items[1].id;
            },
            set: function (itemId) {
                this.items[1] = this.getItem(newValue);
                //update other values
            }
        },
        item2: {
            get: function () {
                return this.items[2].id;
            },
            set: function (itemId) {
                this.items[2] = this.getItem(newValue);
                //update other values
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getItem: function (itemId) {
            //...
        }
    }
});
```

However, given a template like so:

```
<div id="vue-app">
    <span>{{item0}}</span><br/>
    <span>{{item1}}</span><br/>
    <span>{{item2}}</span><br/>
</div>
```

The text for these items is never updated. I have set a breakpoint in the setters and I can confirm that the values are indeed being set correctly. However, the view never recomputes the computed properties (ie the getter is never called again). I understand that computed properties use caching but shouldn't it be invalidated when the underlying data changes? If not is there another way to specify getters and setters for properties?

Codepen recreation of the issue: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OOgNMN

Comment: See [array change detection caveats](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats).  Updated pen https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/mqwEPw?editors=1010.

Comment: Gosh, I knew about this but completely forgot about it in the context of getters and setters. Thanks!